# Star Trek episode where Chakotay and Janeway discuss Maquis' rank not being honored

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

There is an episode of Star Trek: Voyager where Chakotay and Janeway are discussing a data stream they received where the rank given to the marquis was not being honored or was being questioned by Starfleet Command.

Does ANYONE remember what episode this was?  Chakotay and Janeway were on the bridge in their respective seats and talking about it.

Chakotay said something along the lines of "does this surprise you" or something to this effect.  I can't remember the episode.  Someone please help!

Answer (score 26):

Sounds like *[Life Line](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Life_Line_(episode))*

> (Doorbell.)
> JANEWAY: Come in.
>
> CHAKOTAY: Good morning. Problem?
>
> JANEWAY: I haven't decided. I've just listened to a communiqué from Admiral Hayes.
>
> CHAKOTAY: Nice to have friends in high places.
>
> ADMIRAL HAYES [on monitor]: Hello, Captain. I hope this message finds you well. From what I understand, it has not been easy, but I want you to know that a lot of people here are very proud of what you've accomplished. I also want to assure you that we have not given up finding a way to get you home. We've redirected two deep space vessels toward your position. If all goes well, they could rendezvous with you in the next five to six years.
>
> JANEWAY: Computer, advance to time index one twenty one point four.
>
> ADMIRAL HAYES [on monitor]: As we get closer and our conversations become more frequent. When you respond to this message, please let us know of any casualties. I'm sure you've had more than your share. I'm anxious to know the status of your crew, the Maquis, first contacts that you've made, interactions with the Borg. But there'll be time for everything. Our thoughts are with you. Talk to you soon.
>
> CHAKOTAY: What?
>
> JANEWAY: Status of the Maquis.
>
> **CHAKOTAY: Do you find that surprising?**
>
> JANEWAY: I don't think of you or B'Elanna or the others as Maquis. I think of you as part of my crew.
>
> CHAKOTAY: You may have forgotten, but we haven't. You heard the Admiral. It'll be years before we have to deal with those issues. Let's worry about it then.
>
> JANEWAY: Do you have lunch plans?
>
> CHAKOTAY: Is that an invitation?
>
> JANEWAY: I was hoping you'd help me compose a response.
>
> CHAKOTAY: You're on.

---

Regardless of whether this is the correct answer, if you did want to find an episode based on a quote, you could try http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/index.html, which has episode transcripts.

Comment: This is probably the episode requested, even though it doesn't fit the description exactly. I know of no episode which would fill the description exactly.